# How to recursively check for new row, check for a flag and do sum?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I found hard to gave a good description of my question due to the complexity of my operation, I'll try to explain better:

I have this table what I need to achieve is that:

[image]

- Everytime I add a new row a formula has to check if the value of the last colums is "si" and if it's "si" it has to take the value of the colum "total" and sum it into a specific cell, it has to do this operation everytime I add a new row....I tryied many ways and many solutions but with no good...can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `=SUMIFS(F:F, G:G, "si")`. Add this code to any cell on the same sheet, outside the verified ('F' and 'G') columns.
 Please note I assume the columns on the screenshot are 'A' to 'G'. If not, change the referenced cols in the formula accordingly.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Nearly, your solution was half right, I'll post the right answer :)

Comment: My solution is right. I use the latest Excel. Should you mentioned you need the 'signature' of an earlier version.......

Answer (score 0):

This is the right solution:

```
=SUM.IF(G:G;"si";F:F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is `Table1` Total column name is `Total` and column with data si, name is `SI`. Then use following formula in any cell beyond table cells.

```
=SUMIF(Table1[SI],"si",Table1[Total])
```